# sqlite3 date conversion for iMessages chat.db

Tags: database, sqlite

I was looking to extract the iMessages backup db, chat.db, to a text file. I found Matthieu Riegler's wonderful script at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108171/export-imessages-in-human-readable-form-for-archival which does the job very well, with the main query being:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Messages/chat.db "
select is_from_me,text from message where handle_id=(
select handle_id from chat_handle_join where chat_id=(
select ROWID from chat where guid='iMessage;-;$1')
)" | sed 's/1\|/me: /g;s/0\|/budy: /g' > MessageBackup.txt
```

I am trying to figure out how to add the date/time stamp to it. The "date" field is in the message db but it is in a crazy format- an example date value is 382511830000000000. How can I update this query to include the date/time in a normal, readable format?

I tried some of the solutions proposed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/dates-format-in-messages-chat-db but they aren't working for me - I may be applying them wrong as I'm not too familiar with sqlite3.

E.g. I tried changing the second line of the query to:

```
select is_from_me,text,datetime(date + strftime('%s', '2001-01-01 00:00:00'), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as date from message where handle_id=(
```

..but the above got a blank for the dates.

Any idea how to update the query to get the correctly formatted date/time?  Ideally in the local time zone (or in my case PST).

Thank you!